# What formula do i use to scale these numbers

Tags: linear, scales

If x=51 then y=0 and if x=255 then y=2000
Is there such a formula to find y by using an x value between 51-255

Comment: It depends on your assumptions about how x and y relate.

Comment: Linking through the [tag:scales] tag uncovers plenty of answers.